# cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'Date'

Tags: swift, swift3

How do I use the failureReason in passed in curly braces to the method launch, then set the failureReason in the method?

I get this error when calling the launch method: 
cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'Date'

```
firstFalcon.launch() { failureReason in } 

func launch(date: Date = Date()) {
    self.launchDate = date.description
    var failureReason = ""
    if (fuelType == FuelType.water) {
        failureReason = "too much fuel in fuel tank"
    }
}
```

Comment: [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need fixing this error message, you need [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).

Comment: It's not entirely clear why you'd even want to use a closure here in the first place – to me this looks like a case where you probably want the `launch` function to `throw` a custom `LaunchFailure` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it as a parameter to your `launch` method. Right now your `launch` method only expects a date...of type `Date`, and you have given that a default value so you don't have to pass it along.

#### Adding Just a String

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but it seems that the `failureReason` you define in your `launch` method is just a String

```
var failureReason = ""
```

If that is the case, then you should just add another parameter to your `launch` method like so:

```
func launch(date: Date = Date(), failureReason: String)
```

And you can then invoke it like so:

```
launch(failureReason: "boom")
```

#### Adding a Callback Function

If however, you'd would like to pass in a callback function that you can use in your `launch` method, maybe with a failureReason, then you would do it like so:

```
func launch(date: Date = Date(), callback: (String) -> Void)
```

Here you define a function which takes a date and a `callback` function as parameters. The function then takes a `String` as input parameter.

In your `launch` function you do what ever you need to do, and once done, you invoke the `callback` function with a string, so maybe something like:

```
func launch(date: Date = Date(), callback: (String)-> Void) {
    self.launchDate = date.description
    var failureReason = ""
    if (fuelType == FuelType.water) {
       failureReason = "too much fuel in fuel tank"
    }
    callback(failureReason)
}
```

And you can then call that like this:

```
launch() { failureCode in
    print("failed with: \(failureCode)")
}
```

Notice that when your closure/callback is the last parameter in a function you can call it "outside" the parameter list when calling it as I've done above. This is called a "trailing closure" and you can read about it in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Hope I have understood you correctly.

Comment: callback function is what i was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, hope my answer helped you in the right direction. Feel free to mark it as accepted if you feel like it :)